# Why the limit function is bounded?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, proof-explanation, uniform-convergence

The proposition and part of its proof are given below:

> [image]

I am sorry for this question if it is very easy to answer:

In the first line of the proof why the uniform convergence and each $f_{n}$ being bounded leads to the limit function, $f$ is bounded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$|f-f_N| <1$ for some large $N$ by uniform convergence, and then $|f| \leq |f-f_N|+|f_N|$, so $f$ is bounded.